# Kendo UI - 'Errors' of null

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI controls( grid and combo box) in my page, the page works fine in local.
But in server the page is throwing uncaught exception as below.

*In IE8  -
Webpage error details

Message: 'Errors' is null or not an object
Line: 11
Char: 12208
Code: 0
URI: `http://xxxx/Scripts/KendoUI/kendo.web.min.js`

In Chrome -
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Errors' of null.*

Can anyone please advice me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should probably post some sample code. Are you getting an error in js console? Is it during an ajax request? Have you tried setting break points?

Comment: I am using Ajax call from the grid for Create, Read and update. But unable to debug since this works fine in local machine.

Comment: Ok, but for someone to help you they will need to see the code for the grid or combo box. When I say debug I mean using the developer tools in the browser. In Chrome you can access this with f12, and you can set break points and step through the lines of javascript. Also for ajax requests there is a tab called 'Network' that lets you see the HTTP Response of an ajax request. This will let you examine exactly what is being returned of if a 500 status code is being returned then you know it is something on the server.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the first step will be to verify that the url you are using for your ajax is functioning properly. You should be able to navigate to it in a browser (if it is a GET) or use a REST client to issue a post. This eliminates the server as the possibility for the error and then you can focus on the client code that is receiving the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the partial view from controller solved the problem.